# Read T-SQL json column into a varchar variable

Tags: sql-server, json

In SQL Server 2016, how do I set a `varchar` variable value to the json data read from a table?

For example, if I read json data as follows:

```
select column1
from table1
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Then I get an auto-named column like [JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
] with a single row of json data. How can I then copy this value over into a `varchar` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)

set @json = (select column1
from table1
FOR JSON AUTO)
```

Comment: Never mind. Forgot to clear my query. Works for me too. Thank you!

Comment: @Aamir glad to help :)